# fgetcsv() not respecting $enclosure

Tags: php, digest-authentication

I'm working on a script talking to an SMTP server via Sockets, and I'm trying to implement DIGEST-MD5 authentication, but I'm having trouble parsing the string that gets sent back after the AUTH command.

After a `base64_decode()` it looks like:

```
realm="smtp.domain.net",nonce="AJRUc5Jx0UQbv5SJ9FoyUnaZpqZIHDhLTU+Awn/K0Uw=",qop="auth,auth-int",charset=utf-8,algorithm=md5-sess
```

I wanted to use `str_getcsv()`, but the server is still on PHP 5.2, so I got the following code [from the comments on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#100579), and it looks just fine:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('str_getcsv')) {
        function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter=',', $enclosure='"', $escape=null, $eol=null) {
                $temp=fopen("php://memory", "rw");
                fwrite($temp, $input);
                fseek($temp, 0);
                $r = array();
                while (($data = fgetcsv($temp, 4096, $delimiter, $enclosure)) !== false) {
                        $r[] = $data;
                }
                fclose($temp);
                return $r;
        }
}
```

But it returns the following:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => 'realm="smtp.domain.net"',
    1 => 'nonce="2PuESkmrNzGu/5b8N6eIYQoW7mSlScnYAB/PSYebkYo="',
    2 => 'qop="auth',
    3 => 'auth-int"',
    4 => 'charset=utf-8',
    5 => 'algorithm=md5-sess',
  ),
)
```

Note that indexes 2 and 3 should be a single `qop="auth,auth-int"`.

On writing this I realized that maybe `fgetcsv()` expects that the `$enclosure` character contain the entire field and not just part of it, but in that case I have to idea how to properly parse this string.

Comment: If your enclosure is not `"`, use `'`. And if your enclosure is `"`, `realm="smtp.domain.net"` is an invalid string. It should be at least `realm=\"smtp.domain.net\"`.

Comment: @Ninsuo I have no control over the format of the data coming in, it is `realm="smtp.domain.net"` whether I like it or not.

Comment: But can you try to call your `str_getcsv` method with another enclosure? (nice function anyway, I take it for myself ^^)

Comment: Hate when `fgetcsv` gets no respect.

Comment: This isn't a CSV format, so str_getcsv() or fgetcsv() won't work: you could try using parse_str() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php - instead

Comment: @MarkBaker `parse_str()` expects a string formatted like an HTTP query string delimited by `&`, and there's no real way to make change it to `,` without breaking my data.

Comment: str_replace() or a preg_replace() to convert the , to & before executing parse_str() would work, a preg_replace in particular can convert all , outside of the " enclosures

Comment: This is a job for regex. You are trying to use a tool that was not designed for the task which it is being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my googlings for 'PHP DIGEST-MD5' I've come across [a patch for another project](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/issues/attachmentText?id=67&aid=-6363096690198652740&name=DIGEST-MD5.patch&token=04401ad58d386a7c8ef5caac64da7dba) that deals with the same format string with the folowing line:

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)=(?:"([^"]*)|([^,]*))/', $challenge, $matches);
```

Which gives me:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => 'realm="smtp.domain.net',
    1 => 'nonce="AJRUc5Jx0UQbv5SJ9FoyUnaZpqZIHDhLTU+Awn/K0Uw=',
    2 => 'qop="auth,auth-int',
    3 => 'charset=utf-8',
    4 => 'algorithm=md5-sess',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    0 => 'realm',
    1 => 'nonce',
    2 => 'qop',
    3 => 'charset',
    4 => 'algorithm',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    0 => 'smtp.domain.net',
    1 => 'AJRUc5Jx0UQbv5SJ9FoyUnaZpqZIHDhLTU+Awn/K0Uw=',
    2 => 'auth,auth-int',
    3 => '',
    4 => '',
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    0 => '',
    1 => '',
    2 => '',
    3 => 'utf-8',
    4 => 'md5-sess',
  ),
)
```

Then I can fill out a useful array with this loop:

```
$authvars = array();
foreach( $auth_matches[1] as $key => $val ) {
    if( !empty($auth_matches[2][$key]) ) {
        $authvars[$val] = $auth_matches[2][$key];
    } else {
        $authvars[$val] = $auth_matches[3][$key];
    }
}
```

Which gives me:

```
array (
  'realm' => 'ns103.zabco.net',
  'nonce' => 'xITX1qgqlCDmYX6IrctN0WZRx7+Q4W7jjaXCCeUZnU8=',
  'qop' => 'auth,auth-int',
  'charset' => 'utf-8',
  'algorithm' => 'md5-sess',
)
```

It's not exactly pretty, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
$decodedString = 'realm="smtp.domain.net",nonce="AJRUc5Jx0UQbv5SJ9FoyUnaZpqZIHDhLTU+Awn/K0Uw=",qop="auth,auth-int",charset=utf-8,algorithm=md5-sess';

parse_str(preg_replace('/(?:(")(.*?)("))?,(?:(")(.*?)("))?/','$1$2$3&$4$5$6',$decodedString), $values);
var_dump($values);
```

If you want to get rid of the quotes around the resultant array values as well, use

```
$values = array_map(
    function ($value) {
        return trim($value,'"');
    },
    $values
);
var_dump($values);
```